# Why is my php "if statement" not affecting my mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

First of all, I know mysql is deprecated. Will change to mysqli as soon as I figure out the issue at hand. My query continues to update all my rows even if the data is not set in the 'stripetoken' column. Why is this happening?

Code snippet:

```
$token_query = 'SELECT * FROM jobsubmission';
$token_res = mysql_query($token_query);
$token_row = mysql_fetch_array($token_res);


if(isset($token_row['stripetoken'])) {
    $updqry = 'UPDATE jobsubmission SET assigned=1 WHERE ID="'.$book_ids[$jcount].'"';
    $update = mysql_query($updqry);
    $bookdate = date("d-m-Y");
```

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks Pedro. If you read my preliminary paragraph you would see that I had acknowledged that

Comment: Why don't you actually fetch it ? while ($token_row = mysql_fetch_array($token_res)) {  if ($token_row['stripetoken']...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$token_row['stripetoken']` is *always* set because it is a column in your database and it will be available in `$token_row` as a result. Now whether *it has a value* or not is a different story. You should be using `empty()` instead (assuming you don't want it to be true for falsy values).

```
if(!empty($token_row['stripetoken'])) {
```

Comment: Nice to see you back John ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm trying to answer a question or two if I can help it. :)

Comment: You seem to be doing well :-)

Comment: Life is good. :) I should jump in the chat room and say hi sometime soon.

Comment: That's great John, I'm glad to hear it. Life's good here too :-) Looking forward to it, *cheers*

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for that. It should be working, but the query doesn't update anything with the empty(). Tried wrapping in a loop to ensure it was iterating through every row and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

So while @JohnConde was absolutely correct in saying I needed to use the empty function over the isset, my solution layed elsewhere. Here is how I managed to get the query to work to my specifications:

- instead of searching for empty, I made the 'stripetoken' column NULL
  by default.
- This allowed me to use the following code:

  ```
  $token_query = 'SELECT * FROM jobsubmission WHERE ID="'.$book_ids
  [$jcount].'" and stripetoken is not null';
  $token_res = mysql_query($token_query);
  $token_row = mysql_fetch_object($token_res);

  if(!$token_row->stripetoken == NULL) {
  ```

Comment: FYI, `empty()` does *exactly* the same thing